# Reading fortran binary (streaming access) with np.fromfile or open & struct

Tags: python, io, binary, hex

The following Fortran code:

```
INTEGER*2 :: i, Array_A(32)
Array_A(:) = (/ (i, i=0, 31) /)

OPEN (unit=11, file = 'binary2.dat', form='unformatted', access='stream')
    Do i=1,32
        WRITE(11) Array_A(i)
    End Do 
CLOSE (11)
```

Produces streaming binary output with numbers from 0 to 31 in integer 16bit. Each record is taking up 2 bytes, so they are written at byte 1, 3, 5, 7 and so on. The access='stream' suppresses the standard header of Fortran for each record (I need to do that to keep the files as tiny as possible).

Looking at it with a Hex-Editor, I get:

```
00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06 00 07 00 
08 00 09 00 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00
10 00 11 00 12 00 13 00 14 00 15 00 16 00 17 00
18 00 19 00 1A 00 1B 00 1C 00 1D 00 1E 00 1F 00
```

which is completely fine (despite the fact that the second byte is never used, because decimals are too low in my example).

Now I need to import these binary files into Python 2.7, but I can't. I tried many different routines, but I always fail in doing so.

**1. attempt:** "np.fromfile"

```
with open("binary2.dat", 'r') as f:
    content = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int16)
```

returns

```
[    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
    24    25     0     0 26104  1242     0     0]
```

**2. attempt:** "struct"

```
import struct
with open("binary2.dat", 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    struct.unpack('h' * 32, content)
```

delivers

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 64
```

because

```
print content
['\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\t\x00\n', '\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x12\x00\x13\x00\x14\x00\x15\x00\x16\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x19\x00']
```

(note the delimiter, the t and the n which shouldn't be there according to what Fortran's "streaming" access does)

**3. attempt:** "FortranFile"

```
f = FortranFile("D:/Fortran/Sandbox/binary2.dat", 'r')
print(f.read_ints(dtype=np.int16))
```

With the error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

(remember how it detected a delimiter in the middle of the file, but it would also crash for shorter files without line break (e.g. decimals from 0 to 8))

**Some additional thoughts:**

Python seems to have troubles with reading parts of the binary file. For `np.fromfile` it reads `Hex 19` (dec: 25), but crashes for `Hex 1A` (dec: 26). It seems to be confused with the letters, although 0A, 0B ... work just fine.

For attempt 2 the `content`-result is weird. Decimals 0 to 8 work fine, but then there is this strange `\t\x00\n` thing. What is it with `hex 09` then?

I've been spending hours trying to find the logic, but I'm stuck and really need some help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in open file mode. Default it is 'text'. Change this mode to binary:

```
with open("binary2.dat", 'rb') as f:
    content = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int16)
```

and all the numbers will be readed successfull. See Dive in to Python chapter [Binary Files](http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html#binary) for more details.

Comment: Omg, it's one letter? How could I not see this...
Well, thank you so much anyway - saved my day!